# In whose favour almost all suffrages concurred

Tags: sentence-construction, passive-voice

> Every woman had her admirers and her censurers; and the expectations which one raised were by another quickly depressed; yet there was one in whose favour *almost all suffrages concurred.*

I do understand this part, but I wonder why "almost all suffrages concurred" is not "almost all suffrages are concurred?" I think it makes sense if it were a passive.

Comment: Where did you find this excerpt? Please edit and site your source in the question..

Answer (score 0):

*Concur* means *agree*. Why do you think it should be passive?

You may be confused by the unusual use of *suffrage*: I think it here has the OED's sense ii.4.b: "The collective opinion of a group of people; consensus of opinion; common or general consent".